# Start and stop gulp-webserver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-connect

I am trying to start and stop gulp-webserver in different gulp tasks like below:

```
gulp.task('webserver', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.src([config.build, config.base])
    .pipe(webserver({
    livereload: false,
    directoryListing: false,
    open: true
  }));
});

gulp.task('webserver-stop', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src([config.build, config.base])
      .pipe(webserver());
    stream.emit('kill');
});
```

I am able to successfully start the server but when I try to stop the using `gulp webserver-stop`, it gives following error.

```
[19:36:30] Finished 'webserver-stop' after 27 ms
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1253:14)
at listen (net.js:1289:10)
at net.js:1399:9
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:65:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:84:10)
```

I have no significant experience with gulp and javascript before,
Any help to fix this please.

Comment: you're trying to start the server on the same port too fast. you have emitted the event to kill the listener but since it's async you have to restart in another listener callback.

Comment: I want to stop the server instance I had started in above task. Is it possible from another gulp task?

Comment: Are you trying to run `gulp webserver` from one terminal and then `gulp webserver-stop` from another?

Comment: yes, i want to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `gulp webserver` and then `gulp webserver-stop` you have two processes. Those two processes know nothing of each other.

So when you invoke `webserver()` in `webserver-stop` that just starts another webserver instance. It doesn't connect to the already running instance or anything like that. And since there is already one webserver running on port 8000 you get an `EADDRINUSE` error.

Instead your `webserver-stop` task needs to send a message to the running webserver that causes it to shut down.

Since you're already running a webserver you might as well send that message over HTTP. You can use the [`middleware` option](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver#options) of `gulp-webserver` to achieve this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');
var http = require('http');

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
  var stream = gulp.src(['.'])
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: false,
      directoryListing: false,
      open: true,
      middleware: function(req, res, next) {
        if (/_kill_\/?/.test(req.url)) {
          res.end();
          stream.emit('kill');
        }
        next();
      }
    }));
});

gulp.task('webserver-stop', function (cb) {
  http.request('http://localhost:8000/_kill_').on('close', cb).end();
});
```

Now you can invoke `gulp webserver-stop` in another terminal window or simply open [`http://localhost:8000/_kill_`](http://localhost:8000/_kill_) in a browser to shut down the running webserver instance.